# Cannot use !random! in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, random, windows-7-x64

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /p startIndex="Start index: "
set /p endIndex="End index: "

for /l %%a in (%startIndex% 1 %endIndex%) do (
    set /a seed = !random!
    echo %seed%
)
set /p endfile="Wait for it...."
```

I expect that this script will print out some random numbers. But it does not work. It just printed out some lines with same content: "Echo is off ."

How can I fix this code ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to say

```
echo !seed!
```

because the whole loop is parsed at the beginning, and seed is expanded (to nothing, as it doesn't exist yet) before the loop starts running. You therefore need to use delayed expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed expansion is also required on referencing the value of variable `seed` defined and assigned with a random value within a block defined with `(` ... `)`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p "startIndex=Start index: "
set /p "endIndex=End index: "

for /l %%a in (%startIndex% 1 %endIndex%) do (
    set "seed=!random!"
    echo !seed!
)
set /p "endfile=Wait for it ..."
```

Further option `/a` is not necessary to assign a random number to variable `seed` as no arithmetic expression to evaluate. But be careful with spaces around equal sign. All spaces are ignored by **set** on using option `/a`, but are not anymore ignored by command **set** on a simple assignment without option `/a`.

And also take care about where first double quote is written on line with command **set** as this makes a big difference.

For details about spaces around equal sign and first double quote position see answer on
[Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)